# multilingual mongodb mongomapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, multilingual, mongomapper

I have a category collection and each category has a array of hashes containing attributes names and units to create a inout form with, to add a product of that category.

for example category car fields - {name : length, unit : mm}, {name : weight, unit : kg}.

Problem is i would this site to be multi-lingual and therefore need to store the field names per language.

I could put them inline :

for example category car fields - {en-name : length, cn-name : ....., de-name : ....., unit : mm}

Is there a better way ?

Not sure if this is best way as i want to be able to pass a docuement of names needing to be translated to the translator for all field names for all categories, so storing this way i would have to grab all then put into another docuement then translate and inset new translated naes back!!!

Any help or ideas ?

Thanks 
rick

Comment: thanks a lot Michael


I am trying to use your gist in my app and its working on one field called test but if i create a new field called test2 of same type like 

key :test2, LocalizedString

then the value of test3 is the same as test, and i havenet added anything yet for test2.

I dont have to make LocalizedString2 type etc do i as i want to use this for alot of fields.

Please help and thanks a a lot for your help so far this is just what i need.

best regards
Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to put translations in locale files (in config/locales/). For example (english locale):

```
en:
  categories:
    car:
      length: Length
```

And then something like that when displaying name of the field:

```
I18n.t("categories.#{category.name}.#{field_name}")
```

This way you can maintain only one locale file and send the other ones to the translator.

Comment: thanks for the solution.

Only problem is i need to restart the application to pull in new changes to the locale files.  or dont i ?

Also is it possible for my users to add the translation for certain fields to these files from my app ?

thanks

Comment: Yes, you need to restart the app to reload locale files. 

I thought the field names already known and you just need some simple way to translate them, I didn't assume that you'd want your users to add translations via the running app. If that's the case my solution may not be easily applicable. 

Anyway if you need some simple way to work on translations you should check http://99translations.com

Comment: Locale files are fine if you only want the UI to be multi-lingual, but what if you want the content to also be multi-lingual? That is, if you only want spanish content on the spanish version of the site, etc. Would you use separate databases for this? A key-value pair per language, per column? e.g. $obj[name][english] = the table

Answer (score 0):

Model translation is fairly easy in MongoDB.

Here's a gist that uses a custom MongoMapper type to transparently handle localization:  https://gist.github.com/828114

Your LocalizedString would look like

```
name: {  
   en: '...',
   cn: '...',
   de: '...'
}
```

The custom type just stores/returns the value for the current I18n.locale